# Prove that if the outer measure of a set $E$ is the supremum of the measure of closed bdd sets, then $E$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that if the outer measure of a set $E$ is the supremum of closed bdd sets, then $E$ is measurable. More formally, let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and let the outer measure $m_*(E) < +\infty$. Suppose

\begin{align}
m_*(E) = \{m(F): F\subset E \,\, \text{is closed and bounded}\}
\end{align}

Prove $E$ is measurable (Lebesgue).

---

*Proof*. First note that by properties of the supremum, that for any $\epsilon >0$, we can select $F\subset E$ such that

\begin{align}
m_*(E) - m_*(F) < \epsilon
\end{align}

Since $F\subset E$, we also have $E = (E-F) \cup F$. And, since $(E-F)$ is disjoint from $F$

\begin{align}
m_*(E) =& m_*(E-F) + m_*(F) \\ \\ &\implies m_*(E-F) \leq m_*(E) - m_*(F)
< \epsilon
\end{align}

Which implies the outer measure of $(E-F)$ is zero, which implies $(E-F)$ is measurable. Therefore $E$ is the union of measurable sets, which makes it measurable.

Comment: "Prove that if the outer measure of a set $E$ is the supremum of closed bdd sets, then $E$ is measurable. " I don't think that's quite what you meant to say.

Comment: "And since $(E - F)$ is disjoint from $F$, $m_*(E) = m_*(E-F) + m_*(F)$" - why is that? Outer measure isn't additive in general, only subadditive.

Comment: Moreover, $m_*(E-F) < \epsilon$ doesn't imply that $m_*(E-F) = 0$. Your choice of $F$ depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Bungo How about a different argument, that by properties of the supremum, that for any integer $n$ there exists ant $F \subset E$ such that $m_*(E) - 1/n < m(F) < m_*(E) < \inf$ of a measurable set of cubes (by definition). By the squeeze theorem, $m(E) = \sup m(F)$.